# do not copy (ignore) when cell contains specific text

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, filtering

I have the following situation. I have a list of items on Sheet1 and I would like to copy items to Sheet2 and exclude specific items.
Suppose I have the following list of items on Sheet1:

[image: sheet1]

I would like to leave the cell of 'pear' out on Sheet2.
It should leave the pear (ignore) out completely.

It should look like this

[image: sheet2x]

I tried the following but it didn't return the desired results.

=IF(Sheet1!B2="pear", "", "not pear")

the formula I use only substitutes (leaves blank) and looks like this:

Any ideas? Thanks

[image: sheet2]

Comment: You best resort to VBA.

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically, or is it a one-time operation? [Formatting the data as a table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-an-excel-table-6789619f-c889-495c-99c2-2f971c0e2370), [filtering](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e) out "pear", then copying and pasting the remaining table would be quick.

Comment: To do this via formulas, can be done through array formulas. The size of your table and the frequency of running this method can determine whether or not you should go that path. If it's a once of, then definately a quick filter on the range to filter out pear is best, and if it needs automation than VBA is your best bet. As mentioned above by @Luuklag and Itsnotme

Comment: @Luuklag, Itsnotme and JvdV it would not be a one time operation. Thank you for your pointers, l think I need to dig into VBA and or array formulas

Comment: Can you leave blank spaces? `=IF(Sheet1!B2="pear","",B2)` or do you need that one without blank spaces?

Comment: Do you need to keep unique items (without "pear") or should be repeated?

Comment: @ David García Bodego, best would be to leave nothing, it should just skip 'pear'

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Excel formula below for this if you want to refrain from using VBA unless necessary.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,SMALL(IF(NOT($A$2:$A$10="Pear"),ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,1,1))+1),ROWS($C$1:$C1))),"")
```

The result is as shown below

[image: Example in excel]

You can replace the static "Pear" in formula with a cell value if you want to exclude any other word.

Comment: Vikash Sing thanks, this works nice :) Just a small question; is it possible to add more arguments except "Pear". I'm trying "kiwi" but excel notifies me that's to much arguments in one function....

Comment: @ Vikash Singh I tried something like this {"Pear","kiwi"}, but it doesn't do the trick

Comment: For more than one item like {"Pear","Kiwi"} as the equation matches the list in Column A with one item i.e., Pear and gives back an array of true and false wherever Pear was found, As of now excel doesn't provide multiple matches array. Since your question didn't specify you want multiple items I hadn't done, Will look upon it and update if I am able to.

Comment: does someone know how I could use more items in the solution of Vikash SIngh?

Comment: you can use substitute($A$2:$A$10,"kiwi","pear")="pear". The full formula will be `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,SMALL(IF(NOT(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$10,"Kiwi","Pear")="Pear"),ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,1,1))+1),ROWS($C$1:$C1))),"")`